# How to properly encapsulate uncommon fields in JPA entity definition

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I am working on a Java 8 project with an Oracle database. The project uses Spring Boot and JPA. Currently, the JPA Entity is defined in the following manner

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class TestEntity {
     @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(140)")
     private String id;

     @Column(name = "COMMON_FIELD_1", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String commonField1;

     @Column(name = "COMMON_FIELD_2", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String commonField2;

     @Column(name = "UNCOMMON_FIELD_1", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String uncommonField1;

     @Column(name = "UNCOMMON_FIELD_2", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String uncommonField2;
}
```

Here - the fields *id*, *commonField1*, and *commonField2* are present for every database entry and every instance of a TestEntity. The fields *uncommonField1* and *uncommonField2* will not be present in every database entry (null when not present) and will also not be present in every instance of TestEntity.

Although the code functionally does know which uncommon fields to expect in any given instance of TestEntity, it is bad practice to have those fields accessible across every instance of TestEntity. I would like to encapsulate these fields in such a way that only those fields which the code expects to be present are actually accessible.

Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public abstract class TestEntity {
     @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(140)")
     private String id;

     @Column(name = "COMMON_FIELD_1", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String commonField1;

     @Column(name = "COMMON_FIELD_2", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String commonField2;
}


public class TestEntityA extends TestEntity {
     @Column(name = "UNCOMMON_FIELD_1", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String uncommonField1;
}



public class TestEntityB extends TestEntity {
     @Column(name = "UNCOMMON_FIELD_2", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(60)")
     private String uncommonField2;
}
```

Is it possible to implement something like what I've described above? Can my database table contain all 5 columns?

Comment: You need a table for type B and type A in the general TestEntity. Else, you will have rows that don't have information in uncommon field column

Comment: Have a look at "jpa inheritance"